# Gatsby Wordpress ACF Image fields are returning 'null'

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I have a GatsbyJS site consuming data from Wordpress via `gatsby-source-wordpress`. It was all running fine until yesterday, when my queries began to fail. I am using Advanced Custom Fields and can no longer query image fields, my query looks like this when im getting all posts with a post type of 'Project'...

```
allWordpressWpProject {
    edges {
        node {
            title
            slug
            path
            link
            acf {
                project_banner_title
                project_slider_image {
                    source_url
                    alt_text
                }
                project_navigation_image {
                    source_url
                    alt_text
                }
                project_banner_image {
                    source_url
                    alt_text
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But all image fields now return `null`. When I run the query via Wordpress or manually hit the `wp-json` endpoint the image fields return as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue. Suddenly fields no longer work with source_url. It's like gatsby has a limit of some kind and adding content somehow pushes certain pages down and won't process for them.

Comment: @KaiQing Did you find any more info on this, or maybe you've found a fix?

Comment: Sort of. Not in a Gatsby context but more like a wordpress one. By connecting our media library to a CDN and passing the fields as strings instead of having gatsby pull them in the file system we managed to avoid the entire media compiling part of development. In the end, this works fine but on pages with a ton of images we do experience a bit of load time but still better than standard wordpress installs. We upgraded to gatsby 2. I think that helped some too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your acf field is outputting the url for the image rather than the object. If you're using `gatsby-image-sharp` then you ould put those pieces into your query.

```
allWordpressWpProject {
    edges {
        node {
            title
            slug
            path
            link
            acf {
                project_banner_title
                project_slider_image {
                    localFile {
                        childImageSharp {
                            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                project_navigation_image {
                    localFile {
                        childImageSharp {
                            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                project_banner_image {
                    localFile {
                        childImageSharp {
                            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use `gatsby-image` like this:

```
const sliderOne = data.allWordpressWpProject.edges.node.acf.project_slider_image.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid;

<Img fluid={sliderOne} alt={project_banner_title} />
```